# How to use native scroll and use jquery to give it a fix scroll amount(in pixels)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrollbar

I dont want to use any jquery plugin. I want to use the native scrollbar and use jquery so that I can get a fixed scrollamount. 
So far, I needed to use jquery.mousewheel.min.js library to give a fixed scrollamount when using a mousewheel, but no luck in doing the same when dragging the scrollbar or clicking the scrollbutton.
I got this code for mousewheel option:

```
function wheel($div, deltaY) {
var step = 30;
var pos = $div.scrollTop();
var nextPos = pos + (step * (-deltaY))
console.log("DelatY: " + deltaY + ", Step: " + step + ", nextPos: " + nextPos);
$div.scrollTop(nextPos);
}

$('#test').bind('mousewheel', function (event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    if (delta > -2 && delta < 2) {
        wheel($(this), deltaY);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    console.log(delta);
});
```

Comment: what is the delta, deltaX and  deltaY ???

Answer (score 0):

**the event is not being bind with control,try below one**

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#test').bind('mousewheel', function (event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
            if (delta > -2 && delta < 2) {
                wheel($(this), event.clientY);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            console.log(delta);
        });
    });
```

as well as parameter ***`delta, deltaX, deltaY`*** value is also pass as undefined so please provide value for the same.